# Xamarin Forms : Android Build Error

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build an android project of a Xamarin Forms project. But getting the error as in image 1.

I am targeting Android 26 and building against build tool 26.0.2.

I have shared the details of SDK and installed packages.

I have tried **clearing all the Nuget cache**, **deleting obj and bins** in all the projects, **installing the V7.AppCompact package manually**.

Can anyone help me on this.I know this is a very common issue but I dont know what I am doing wrong.

[image: Error after Building][image: Packages Details][image: SDk Details][image: SDK1]

Styles.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/a</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDateStyle</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDateStyle</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDateStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Have you changed your styles.xml?

Comment: @hichame.yessou No , do we need to change the styles.xml ?

Comment: I would delete the styles that you're not using, delete all the files in Packages folder of your project and all the folders (except "Mono for Android") under the path: C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Xamarin

Comment: @hichame.yessou Tried everything !

Comment: Seems it was an incompatibility between nugget versions, did you use some third-part nuget package?